# ReferenceError: $traceurRuntime is not defined (in angularjs app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, ecmascript-6, gulp-traceur

I'm using [gulp-traceur][1] to compile es6 to js in my angularjs application (1.x). When I try and compile a `for` loop, I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: $traceurRuntime is not defined
```

It looks like I need to inject $traceurRuntime into my controller or something. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$traceurRuntime` is an object in the global scope, not an Angular injectable. This object comes from including the traceur runtime script file (`traceur-runtime.js`) in your app. [Make sure you include the `traceur.RUNTIME_PATH`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-traceur#traceurruntime_path) so the gulp task knows where to find it during compilation and includes it.

Assuming your gulpfile looks something like this:

```
// gulpfile.js
var traceur = require('gulp-traceur');

// ...

gulp.task('build', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    traceur.RUNTIME_PATH, // <-- add this
    'src/**/*.*'
  ])
  .pipe(traceur({ /* traceur config */ })
  .pipe(gulp.dest('/dist'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can find out the runtime path? Is it where traceur lives? For me this is: /usr/local/bin/traceur

Comment: @Rimian Phrasing was a bit off. You should set the runtime path as an entry for gulp.src, so that it's pulled in. Updated the answer.